# Connecting uwsgi with Nginx does not work

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

### Solved

> #### see bottom for fixes etc.

I'm trying to connetc my django app with nginx via uwsgi, but it seems that the passing of data to uwsgi does not happen. I've tested that the uwsgi server is running properly and do not get any log output on either end.

> uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = MyDjangoApp.wsgi:application
master = True

;http-socket = :8001 #to run uwsgi on its one to ensure that it works

socket = :8001

vacuum = True
max-requests = 5000
plugin = python3
enable-threads = True
```

> /etc/nginx/sites-available file tree
>
> > - default
> > - serverDjango_nginx.conf
>
> serverDjango_nginx.conf:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 127.0.0.1; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
   # location /media  {
# location /media  {
   #     alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files $
   # }

   # location /static {
   #     alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files$
   # }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/pi/Server/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you in$
    }
```

## UPDATE:

first the site wasn't enabled...
second I've put a link to it in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ as the documentation said
now i get this wierd error:

> 2020/03/29 12:14:18 [emerg] 4344#4344: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/serverDjango_nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63

I looked into the corresponding config file to find

```
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

and now I am wondering why id does not find the file I've linked to

> sudo ln -s ~/etc/nginx/sites-available/serverDjango_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

## Update No2

so the linkagepath was wrong because of:

> sudo ln -s ***~***/etc/nginx/sites-available/serverDjango_nginx.conf

the tilde there, which forced a relative path, therefore invalidating the link

Answer (score 1):

This [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx) is a great tool for generating your Nginx config files. In your `server` block you should be putting the `listen` to either `80` or `443` (if you want it to be accessible via standard http/s ports). You also should put your `server_name` to be your domain such as `www.google.com google.com` (yes include both) or whatever domain(s) you want to serve your Django site on.

I don't use the uwsgi like you do under location either. I just use `proxy_pass` like `proxy_pass http://localhost:8001` and then pass an `include` for my proxy config.